# Incorrect CSS target for Text color

Tags: html, css

I have 2 CSS elements defined, one called horizontalmenu and another called footer-links. For some reason when I change the hover text color for one of the divs, it changes it for both.

Below is the HTML and CSS for the 2 sections in question.

HTML

```
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 

<li> <a href="#">Products</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Managed Networks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Disaster Recovery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cloud</a></li>
</ul> 
</li> 

<li> <a href="#">Why Indigo?</a></li>

<li> <a href="#">About Us</a></li>

<li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="bottombar">

        <div class="copyright">
        <h7>&copy; Copyright 2014 Company name</h7>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">GC24</a>&nbsp;|
        <a href="#">Call Rates</a> 
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.horizontalmenu  a:link, a:visited{
color: #003399 !important;
}

#horizontalmenu li ul  li:hover a,
#horizontalmenu li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;

.footer-links a:link, a:visited{
    font: 'Gill Sans MT';
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.footer-links a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Could someone help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma does not have the precedence you think it does.

`.horizontalmenu  a:link, a:visited` means:

> Anchors that are unvisited links and descended from elements that are members of the horizontalmenu class
>   **and**
>   anchors that are visited links.

It does **not** mean:

> Anchors that are unvisited links and descended from elements that are members of the horizontalmenu class
>   **and**
>   anchors that are visited links and descended from elements that are members of the horizontalmenu class

You need:

```
.horizontalmenu  a:link, .horizontalmenu a:visited
```

(And similar for all your other instances of the same problem)